# GitHub Api: How to get Root :tree_sha of a repository?

Tags: github, github-api

How do I get the Root :tree_sha of a GitHub repository via the GitHub API?

The GitHib API help pages don't seem to explain this critical piece of information:

http://develop.github.com/p/object.html

> Can get the contents of a tree by tree
>   SHA
>
> tree/show/:user/:repo/:tree_sha
>
> To get a listing of the root tree for
>   the facebox project from our commit
>   listing, we can call this:
>
> $ curl
>   http://github.com/api/v2/yaml/tree/show/defunkt/facebox/a47803c9ba26213ff194f042ab686a7749b17476

Comment: You can always use `HEAD` that is the current tree

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://develop.github.com/p/commits.html

The commit tells you its tree sha.

[EDIT]
If you want the tree sha of a subfolder cd into the parent folder of the one you're  interested in and run:
`git ls-tree HEAD`

If you want Root tree sha:
`git show HEAD --format=raw`
1st line has commit sha
2nd line has tree sha

Answer (score 14):

Each commit contains the sha of the entire tree as of that commit. 
Use the API to get a JSON object representing the `master` branch.

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/branches/master
```

That branch's last commit includes the tree's sha that I think you're asking for.

This bit of code demonstrates how to get the `head_tree_sha` in Python.

```
import requests
token = '0...f'
key = {'Authorization':'token '+token}
master = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/'+owner+'/' + repo '/branches/master', headers=key)
master = master.json()
head_tree_sha = master['commit']['commit']['tree']['sha']
```

https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the GitHub API — however if you want just the hash you can use this command in your clone:

```
git show HEAD --format=%T | head -1
```

Or use `%t` for the abbreviated hash.

Comment: This works well but I'm afraid to vote it up because the question was specific to GitHub.